# Samsung Gear 2 wired notification

Tags: watch, samsung-galaxy-gear

Recently, i started getting wired alerts on my Samsung Gear2. 
When I look at my watch, it says that there is a new sms with Unknown sender and when I choose show in phone, it says Failed!

It keeps alerting me with unknown sms and I do not know what is the source of these alerts.

see attachment [picture of the watch with unknown message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXmIf.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Reset the device, or relink it at least. Could be a bug in the underlying system. Might also have some dodgy stuff on your phone.

Comment: so far, no strange messages after reset :-) thanks for the suggestions